# Accessing properties across pages in AEM HTL (Sightly)

Tags: reference, carousel, aem, sightly, aem-6

I have a carousel component, whose slide content will be the content from another page, accessed via reference component. I want to get some properties authored in the carousel to be accessible inside the referenced page. i.e. I have Page A- with a Carousel accessing PageB through reference component. I want to get proeprties from PageA in PageB. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can, you will need to lookup/query the content and find pages where `PageB` is included, then get the properties of those pages (there might be more than one) and merge them. It will have to be custom code though as this is not available out-of-the-box as of AEM 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be adding a query parameter or setting a request parameter. But then again, this depends on the requirement. For me, this worked!!